# Get rid of repetitive characters from a column name in R

Tags: r

Here is a portion of my large dataframe

```
> a
  SS29.SS29  PP1.PP1  SS4.SS4 CC43.CC43 FF57.FF57 NN23.NN23 MM25.MM25  KK9.KK9  MM55.MM55  AA75.AA75 SS88.SS88
1  669.9544 1.068153 35.86534  24.47688  1.058007  72.20306  1.854856 10.15414 0.08715572 0.02006310 0.1817582
2  651.2092 1.164428 37.59895  27.41381  1.095322  73.48029  1.927993 10.09958 0.09096972 0.02261701 0.1855258
```

How I'd be able to get rid of the double column names separated by a dot? e.g. for the first column I'd like to have SS29 instead of repetitive SS29.SS29, for the second column PP1 and so on. Is there any automated way of doing it?

Comment: I recommend looking up regular expressions, both in general and how you can use them in R.

Comment: Seeing your sample, something like this? `gsub("\\..*$", "", x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sub`

```
names(a) <- sub("[.](.*)", "", names(a))
# [1] "SS29" "PP1"  "SS4"  "CC43" "FF57" "NN23"  
# [7] "MM25" "KK9"  "MM55" "AA75" "SS88"
```

or a `substring`

```
substring(names(a), 1, regexpr("[.]", names(a))-1)
# [1] "SS29" "PP1"  "SS4"  "CC43" "FF57" "NN23"
# [7] "MM25" "KK9"  "MM55" "AA75" "SS88"
```

or `strsplit`

```
names(a) <- unlist(strsplit(names(a), "[.](.*)"))
# [1] "SS29" "PP1"  "SS4"  "CC43" "FF57" "NN23" 
# [7] "MM25" "KK9"  "MM55" "AA75" "SS88"
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use `sub` to remove the substring after the dot `.` character.

```
names(a) <- sub('\\.[^.]*', '', names(a))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can assign new column names with

```
colnames(a) <- new_column_names
```

To compute `new_column_names`, you can use regular expressions, e.g.. the `gsub` function, as ssdecontrol suggested.

```
new_column_names <- gsub(...)
```

Comment: So you're not actually going to provide a solution?

Comment: @RichardScriven: Oh, I think I did.